# jQuery.find() does not find elements

Tags: jquery, find, selector

I am new to jQuery and I came across a Problem with the find function.
I got the following two lines in my code 
Copy code

```
console.log($('ul.gallery'));
console.log($("ul.gallery").find("img"));
```

And the output in Opera Dragonfly looks like that

[Dragonfly console output](http://i46.tinypic.com/2hqcokk.png)

As you can see, the find function does not find the img tags, but as you can also see, it is there.
I don't know if this has something to do with that strange <::after> tag. And I don't know where this comes form. But I need a reference to that img tags. And can't get it.

//edit:
The <::after> tags are shown in dragonfly with opera 12.01, as a matter of fact they aren't shown in firefox, but the result is the same, they arent selected. If I use the selector on static html tags they work. maybe my difficulties are the result of the recently manipulation of the dom.

Can you please help me?
Kind regards
Angelo Hannes

Comment: What happens if you change it to console.log($("ul.gallery a").find("img")) instead? I think it probably is the <::after> thing messing the results up. I have never had problems with find(), it's been in the API for years...

Comment: Can you post relevant html on jsfiddle?

Comment: What exactly is the output you're looking for?

Comment: the change danwellman suggested doesn't change anything. no child of ul can be found. please give me some time for jsfiddle, so I can try it. @Likwid_T I want the child images

Comment: I don't know how to get a running example on jsfiddle. But here is the link where I'm testing https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13837103/BBdraft/src/main.html#fbgallery It happens after clicking on the FBlogin

Comment: it works fine on my opera9.80 dragonfly http://jsfiddle.net/TuU3z/6/ could you be more specific, what is your browser's version ?

Comment: are you adding elements dynamically? it could be that `.find` is running before the `img` exists in the DOM

Comment: yes I'm adding these elements dynamically, but they exist in the DOM because the console.log in the line before shows these elements. Or am I wrong whith that?

Comment: I just discovered, that I can find the elements with findElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.
As it seems, Opera Dragonfly shows elements, that were not in the dom at the time of selection.
That was very confusing. But thank you all very much!